# How to get rid of garbage in logfile?

Tags: logging, arangodb

I'm running ArangoDB 3.0.1 on Windows 7.

The size of the logfile my installation creates is about 11.000K immediatly after startup. The file starts with about 11.000K "NUL" bytes (shown as 'NUL' in notepad++), followed by the usefull  text information. This is pretty annoying when trying to debug some Foxx service and having to reloaed the logfile numerous times into a text viewer/editor.

Deleting the logfile or creating or removing all contents after ArangoDB started does not help either: 11.000K NUL bytes will be written first.

Is there a way to get rid of all this NUL garbage?

P.S.: Log level is set to INFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably messed up the [wal logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449237/arangodb-journal-logfiles/) with the log file as in outputting log messages.

According to the arangod.conf the log messages file can be found here:

```
[log]
level = info
file = log/arangodb3/arangod.log
```

which shouldn't show this behaviour, but instead get filled with the output of the log messages. It can be that you need to alter this setting specifying a better location to make it get written.

Your log messages should also get written to the windows event log.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I just changed the name of the logfile for a quick test, and now it contains only the log messages I want to see.

Comment: I checked again: The log file and the journals were in different dirctories all the time, so this was probably not the cause. I also went back to the prior configuration and could not reproduce the bahaviour. So I have no idea what actually went wrong. Let's leave it like this.