# Arangodb journal logfiles

Tags: arangodb

What for are logfiles in:

```
"arango_instance_database/journals/logfile-xxxxxx.db
```

Can I delete them ?

How can I reduce their size ?
I set

```
database.maximal-journal-size = 1048576
```

but those files are still 32M large.

Can I set some directory for them like

```
/var/log/...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the [Write Ahead Logfiles](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Configuration/Wal.html) which are at least temporarily the files your data is kept in.

So its **a very bad idea** to remove them on your own, as long as you still like your data to be intact.

The files are used so documents can be written to disk in a contineous fashion. Once the system is idle, the aggregator job will pick the documents from them and move them over into your database files.

You can find [interesting documentation of situations where others didn't choose such an architectural approach, and data was written directly into their data files on the disk](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Inside_the_RRDtool_plugin), and what this then does to your sytem.

Once all documents in a WAL-file have been moved into db files, the ArangoDB will remove the allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You a lot for reply :-)

So in case of arangodb deployed as "single instance" I can set:

```
--wal.suppress-shape-information true
--wal.historic-logfiles 0
```

Anything else ?

How about

```
--wal.logfile-size
```

What are best/common practises in determining its size ?

Comment: `suppress-shape-information` isn't available in 3.0 anymore. Reducing `logfile-size` will probably end up in more of them being used, however they may be removed faster. `historic-logfiles` are needed to possibly re-sync replicas; if you decide to throw them away quicker, a replication may not be able to catch up after a netsplit anymore.

Comment: @ dothebart  
But --wal.suppress-shape-information is still present in official documentation for 3.0.  

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Configuration/Wal.html  

So how/ to who can I report to update documentation ?

Comment: me ;-) https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/b96cdf4ba8adf2886fbc0ef3bb1c1da94be6b01e Thanks for reporting.